# How to list directories a certain level deep using the Tree command in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, tree

i would like to list all the directories down to a specified level with the Tree command. I like the way the Tree command sorts and uses the ASCII to show the directories or folders, and all the folders within those folders.

This is what i have so far. I would like to modify this command with like -Depth 2 or something like that. This command as it stands works great for listing all the directories but i only want them down to a certain level. I hope this helps you help me:)

Tree | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Set-Content list20.txt

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927324/cmd-tree-command-limit-number-of-levels

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54988288/10592356

Comment: these don't seem to work with PowerShell, only the CMD prompt app. I cannot use The CMD prompt unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

Tree is not a PowerShell cmdlet, as we know, and as such cannot be used in the vein you are trying to do.

For what you are after, you have to write this yourself or look for something already done.

You cannot filter external .exe(s) as you can with say Get-ChildItem, and such, without capturing all its output as an object then, using the normal object walking efforts available.

If you search for such solutions, you'd come across these examples:

[PowerTip: Limit Get-Childitem to a limited depth in the tree](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-limit-get-childitem-to-a-limited-depth-in-the-tree)

```
Get-Childitem C:\Users\CurlyBlue -include *.docx -depth 2
```

[PowerTip: View Directory List as Tree by Using PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-view-directory-list-as-tree-by-using-powershell)

```
Show-Tree e:\data –depth 2
```

[Powershell Directory Tree](https://mangolassi.it/topic/15499/powershell-directory-tree)

```
get-childitem -Path Q:\ -Recurse -Directory -Depth 3|select FullName|export-csv C:\file-tree.csv


# or this way

(get-childitem -Path d:\projects -Recurse -Directory -Depth 2).FullName
```

There are a number of other options to dig at this as well. All searchable on the web.

For example:
[See also](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Tree/1.0.1)

List contents of directories in a tree-like format with colorization and lots of options